# NSPredicate with regex to check alphanumeric

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I want to check string with regex in Objective c. My code

```
NSString *regexAmazonOrder =@"[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
NSPredicate *predicateAmazonOrder = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regexAmazonOrder];

if([predicateAmazonOrder evaluateWithObject:cardNumber.text])
{
    NSLog(@"Its coming inside AMAZON ORDER EVALUATIONS");
    ...
}
```

But its not working. Help me out. I know its simple but eating my mind!!! Thanks

Comment: What doesn't seems to work ? If you want to use regex use `NSRegularExpression` class. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Your code seems to work... Can you provide a sample string that fails for you?

Comment: @ Alladinian - femitestcard2013

Comment: @Meenu Well... just tested and it works. You could add a breakpoint or an `NSLog` statement just before the evaluation to check that `cardNumber.text` is indeed what you expect it to be. Also check for any whitespace since it would break the matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:  (Untested, just to give you an starter)

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z0-9]*"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:cardNumber.text
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

if([matches count] > 0)
{
   // Valid input
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you are back in business.:)

Answer (score 5):

Here is shorter version:

```
+(BOOL)isAlphanumericString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *filter = @"[a-z0-9]*";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", filter];
    return [predicate evaluateWithObject:string];
}
```