# Nspredicate for matching string contains specified characters

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Is there a way we can use nspredicate like this?

String = whvat

I want to search the string if it contains these characters [what]{4}. This will not return true for the above string since v is not found. I basically want a predicate to return true if a string contains 'n' specified characters. There can be other characters in the string but the specified should be definitely present. Order of characters does not matter. Even if I give [hwta] it should still give me the word whvat because 4 specified characters are found

Comment: You can use regex in NSPredicate. Use `MATCHES` (doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567243/nspredicate-with-regex-to-check-alphanumeric etc. Looking for "Regex + NSPredicate" should give you results.

Comment: I tried MATCHES [what]{4} but it did not work

Comment: The string should have at least 4 chars provided in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant but you could try to make predicate for each character:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains 'w' and self contains 'h' and self contains 'a' and self contains 't'"];
NSString *string = @"what";
NSLog(@"%d ", [p evaluateWithObject:string]);
```